# Typescript Expects Arguments Inspite of Defaults Provided to Function Arguments

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have code which looks like this :

```
export default async function logout(
  _: null = null,
  ctx: { session?: SessionContext } = {}
): Promise<void> {
  return await ctx.session!.revoke();
}
```

Usage:

```
<a
onClick={async (): Promise<void> => {
  await logout();
  ...
}}>
Logout
</a>
```

After searching through the questions here, I tried the suggested solution of adding expected outcome from the async function in the form `Promise<void>` & explicitly defining `null` type to the first arg. However, during the build process (Linter doesnt show any errors in VsCode editor), it fails with the error: `Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 0.`

What am I missing from the definitions to make it pass.

Comment: Please show us the code where you are getting the error, i.e. the import statement and call. Are you sure you're calling the right function?

Comment: Works in the playground: https://tsplay.dev/ymA9Xm